# How to replace a fragment from onOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've got an *AppCompatActivity* which is the main *View* of the app.
There I've got an *OptionsMenu* with a button to display a *drawer menu* and another button to filter the results (Because each *MenuItem* in the drawer are different *Listfragments*).

What I need to accomplish is, when clicking the filter button on the *OptionsMenu*, open a *fragment* with all the filtering criteria.

So this is the code managing the explained above:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_menu:

            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                hideDrawer();
            } else {
                showDrawer();
            }

            return true;
        case R.id.action_filter:

            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragment = new FilterFragment();
            args.putInt("idList", idList);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Doing that the Fragment shows up and then I get a **NPE**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableRow.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

**Fragment onCreateViewMethod**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    skbrDays = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    daysLostRow = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.daysLostRow);
    genderRow = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.genderRow);
    locationRow = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.locationRow);
    rgupGender = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rgupGender);
    rgupType = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rgupType);
    btnBreed = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnBreed);
    recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    daysLostRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter, container, false);
}
```

Ok, so I'm getting the NPE because *getActivity()* is returning *null*. And now I have to guess, not really knowing the reason, that is beacuse I'm not replacing the fragment on *onCreate* method from the activity?

If that is the reason how can I achieve the same result calling the fragment from *onCreate*?

Comment: It's not `getActivity()`. It's `findViewById(R.id.daysLostRow)`. You may want to throw that fragment code away and start again: fragments should not generally depend on the kind of activity that uses them.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov but findViewById() is not an inherited method by Fragment

Comment: yes, but your exception doesn't say "*attempted to invoke findViewById on a null object reference*" either, which means `getActivity()` returns something. However, `setVisibility` is only called once in code you're showing, which means `daysLostRow` is `null`. And where did that variable came from, you think?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you are right getActivity() isn't returning null. daysLostRow is a global variable previously defined. But the problem isn't with that particular variable, any method I call on any of the other Views give me a NPE.

Comment: That would be because it is `null`. Most likely because original activity doesn't have any elements with `R.id.daysLostRow` in its view.

Comment: Mm... No, the original activity doesn't have it. It is defined inside the Fragment class.

Comment: Then there you have it. You are trying to get something which activity doesn't have, so it returns you `null` instead. To do what you want, you will need to first create (inflate) the view from its `layout-id`, and then search *that* for a view with id.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I understand now. Isn't that what Hiral Pancholi proposed?

Comment: It is. It is also a duplicate of the other question I linked. Hiral's answer is also not a good one, because it doesn't explain anything, she just "writes the code instead of you".

Comment: Yeah, I know is not a good answer. But It solved the problem, I would have liked that she explained why it worked. If you would've posted the solution as an answer I had chosen yours.

Comment: I don't think I need to. There is already a highly viewed question and an answer to it out there. This question's title is misleading as well, so it's unlikely to help future readers who would look for something related to `onOptionsItemSelected`, because this question actually isn't related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code in onCreateView to below code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    skbrDays = rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    daysLostRow = rootView.findViewById(R.id.daysLostRow);
    genderRow = rootView.findViewById(R.id.genderRow);
    locationRow = rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationRow);
    rgupGender = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgupGender);
    rgupType = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgupType);
    btnBreed = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnBreed);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    daysLostRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. Would you explain me why what I was doing wasn't working and your code did?

Comment: While that is a potential way to fix the code, without explanation of why it works this is not a good answer.